# How to display the top 5 popular links in the header?

Tags: popular-posts

I want to display the top 5 popular links in the header. How will I do this?

Also want to display the page hits in the brackets with the links.

Any one who can help?

Comment: What do you mean by links? I guess you mean Posts.

Comment: What are you using to track the page hits, and how is its data stored?

Comment: @technoTitan links means pages.

Comment: @m0r7if3r currently I am not using anything for it.

Comment: So...are you asking how to track page hits and then sort by them?

Comment: @m0r7if3r yes I want this.

Comment: If you have space in the header, you could register a widget area (sidebar) in functions.php, and place it in the header. That would allow you to use one of the plugins that already displays your most popular posts. Would that be something like what you would want?

Comment: How could I register a sidebar in functions.php?

Comment: @ m0r7if3r - I believe what he wants is exactly that - first track and then query that tracking system ..

Answer (score 1):

Put this in your functions.php file

```
function k99_post_hits( $id, $action ) {
        $dl_HitMetaField    = '_dl_post_hits'; // hidden Custom field that stores the views
        $dl_PostHits    = get_post_meta($id, $dl_HitMetaField, true);
        switch ($action) {
        case 'count' :
        if ( $dl_PostHits =='' ) {
            $dl_PostHits = mt_rand(10,20);//just for debug-test - remove for real count
            delete_post_meta( $id, $dl_HitMetaField);
            add_post_meta( $id, $dl_HitMetaField, $dl_PostHits );
            }
            $dl_PostHits++;
            update_post_meta( $id, $dl_HitMetaField, $dl_PostHits );
            break;
        case 'display' :
        echo 'this page was viewed: ' , $dl_PostHits ;
} 
}
```

and this :

```
function k99_most_popular() {
global $wp_query, $post, $paged, $post_count;

    // YOUR QUERY
    $query_args = array (
        'meta_key' =>'_dl_post_hits', 
        'orderby' => 'meta_value',
        'order' => ASC ,
        'posts_per_page' => 5 // how many we want ?
    );    

    // SAVE CURRENT QUERY
    $temp = $wp_query;
    $wp_query= null;    

    // CREATE NEW QUERY
    $wp_query = new WP_Query();
    $wp_query->query($query_args);      
$output ='<span>';
        // THE LOOP, DO WHAT YOU HAVE TO DO HERE
        while ($wp_query->have_posts()) : $wp_query->the_post(); {   
$output .= '<li><a href="' .get_permalink() .'" title="' . get_the_title(). '"/>'. get_the_title() .'</a></li>';
}
        endwhile;  
$output .= '</span>';       
echo $output;

        // SWAP BACK THE PREVIOUS QUERY
        $wp_query = null; 
        $wp_query = $temp;
        wp_reset_query();   
}
```

then , in the template file you want to track (typically post &/or single &/or page)

put this in side the loop (preferably as first function before any output):

```
<?php k99_post_hits( $post->ID, 'count' );  //adding post counter ?>
```

then - wherever you would like to DISPLAY the count, put this :

```
<?php k99_post_hits( $post->ID, 'display' );  //adding post counter ?>
```

to get most "viewed"

```
 <?php k99_most_popular(); //getting post list by views ?>
```